# Using loopback-connector-remote to call custom method in another loopback service doesn't create correct URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to connect 2 loopback services, let's say **A** and **B**, using **loopback-connector-remote** datasource.

On **B** I have this custom remote method:

```
/api/B/myModel/myMethod/{id}
```

This method works fine if I access the API explorer on **B** service.

Then on **A** service I want to access this method so I created the following configuration (which is the same on **B** too) on the remote model object:

```
myModel.remoteMethod(
   'myMethod',
    {
     http: {path: '/myMethod/:id', verb: 'get'},
      accepts: [
       {arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true}
      ],
      returns: {type: 'object', root: true}
    }
 );
```

From **A** I can do any call to **B** like find, findById, etc. But When I call this custom method I get this error on **A**:

> strong-remoting:rest-adapter Error in GET /myModel/myMethod/1231: Error: id must be a number

And looking at the logs in **B** I saw that **A** is calling the service like this:

> strong-remoting:rest-adapter Error in GET /myModel/myMethod/:id?id=1231: Error: id must be a number

Why is **strong-remoting** or **loopback-connector-remote** not replacing the id correctly when the URL is created? Did I missed something on the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add source path to the remote method configuration in the **A** service model object:

```
{ arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true, http: { source: 'path' }}
```